# Function: Check value doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think the code expains what the problem is. I want to check if the color is blue or not. I think this is the problem "$(color)" but i don't know how to fix this.

```
function test(color) {

                if ( $(color) == 'blue' ) {
                     // DO SOMETHING
                } else {
                     // DO SOMETHING
                }      

            }

            test("green");
```

UPDATE: I added some code because i tried to change the $(color) to color an this doesn't work. Here is the full code:

```
function test(color) {

            if ( color == 'blue' ) {
                 $('#name').change( function() {
            } else {
                 $('#email').change( function() {
            }

            });

        }

        test("green");
```

Comment: Use `color == 'blue'`, Why are you creating jQuery object?

Comment: people need to learn some basic js before using jq..

Comment: what you want when color is blue?? because `$('#name').change( function() {`  is wrong

Comment: What are you trying to do? As your problem sounds to be `You want to check if the color is blue or not.`, that should have been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use dollar for color variable.
So your code will be:

```
function test(color) {
  var id;
  (color === 'blue') ? (id = '#name') : (id = '#email'); 
  $(id).change( function() {
     /* your code */
  }); 
}

test("green");
```

Answer (score 3):

no use of **$**
there is no need to use `$` before the javascript variable

```
 function test(color) {
        if (color== 'blue' ) {
             // DO SOMETHING
        } else {
             // DO SOMETHING
        }
 }
test("green");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change :

```
 if ( $(color) == 'blue' ) {
```

to:

```
 if ( color == 'blue' ) {
```

color is variable not an object.

Answer (score 0):

`$` is mostly used alias(short name) for jQuery in javascript. I think, you comes from `Shell Script` world where you have to use `$` prefix to access the value of the variable. But in javascript, 
just use variable name.

**Javascript**

```
 var name = 'kumar';
 alert(name)
```

**Shell script**

```
name=kumar
echo $name
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regulare expressions for this easy job:

```
function test(color) {
    if (/blue/.test(color)) {
         // DO SOMETHING
    } else {
         // DO SOMETHING
    }
```

}
test("green");